# Paperclip with valums's file-uploader

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip

I am using Paperclip to upload image on Rails3. Now I want to use valums's file-uploader to do multiple image upload. I have already set the multiple image upload correctly.
Each Product(a particular model) has_many photos.
each photo has_one item. (FROM: rails g paperclip photo item)
My question is how to use valums's file-uploader?
And JackDanger write a Rack::RawUpload, how to use it ?
Thank you very much>

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help

http://mooooooooooo.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/paperclip-valums%E2%80%99s-file-uploader-and-middleware-continued/#comment-16

i'm currently trying to do the same, and i think i've almost done